# How to extract text from time tag with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to extract all text from a 'time' tag.
The HTML is from this page : https://www.python.org

Here is my code:

```
event_times = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".event-widget time")
    
for time in event_times:
    print(time.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

I have this output:

```
<span class="say-no-more">2021-</span>11-13
<span class="say-no-more">2021-</span>11-15
<span class="say-no-more">2021-</span>11-18
<span class="say-no-more">2021-</span>11-19
<span class="say-no-more">2021-</span>11-24
```

If I change to :

```
for time in event_times:    
    print(time.text)
```

The output:

```
11-13
11-15
11-18
11-19
11-24
```

My question : is there a direct way to display all the text contained in the time tag, namely `2021-11-13`, `2021-11-15`, etc...?

Except to separate into two searches (in span for "year" and in time for "month-day"), I don't see how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all the texts from the `<time>` tags e.g. *2021-11-05*,  using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.menu>li time")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='menu']/li//time")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['2021-11-05', '2021-11-02', '2021-10-26', '2021-10-19', '2021-10-18', '2021-11-13', '2021-11-15', '2021-11-18', '2021-11-19', '2021-11-24']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```